# Vue-select drop-down not working properly

Tags: html, vue.js

I am using vue-select to create normal drop-down list. but it's having search bar in it by default which i don't required and want to keep it simple. I tried doing "display: none" for that search bar which will be disappeared.

Image is what I am getting now.

```
<wifi-select class="wifi-login__string" placeholder="String" :options="['String','Email','Date']" :clearable="false"> </wifi-select>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give jsfiddle

Comment: hi @Ademyalçın thanks for replying but i think i have figured it out the wrong thing, i was using "vue-select" but was not importing CSS which supports it. I have used `import "vue-select/dist/vue-select.css";` and it worked for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i was using vue-select which does support various drop-downs, but doesn't has it's own CSS and thus we have to import CSS

`import "vue-select/dist/vue-select.css";`